# JS (CSS) dynamic background image moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made up a little script that makes a photo background to scroll up/button in same time with page scrolling. The problem is that the background image is scrolling after the page was scrolling (it have a delay).

Question: How may I make to move background image with page scrolling like in this example http://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524936-unika-responsive-one-page-html5-template/live-demo ?

I made a plnkr with my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/e6OCUF4sXSA80Pi6XANj?p=preview

```js
var bgScroll = function(lastScrollTop, elem) {
  lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(elem).css('transition', 'all .5s');
  $(elem).css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-lastScrollTop / 2) + 'px');
  console.log('lastScrollTop = ' + lastScrollTop);
};
$(window).load(function() {
  var lastST = 0;
  var homeElem = '#add-outer-container';
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    bgScroll(lastST, homeElem);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
#add-outer-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff url(http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg) no-repeat fixed 0% 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- version 0.6.1.0 -->
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="add-outer-container"></div>
  <div style="height: 1500px; color: green;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your are looking for is called **parallax** effect. There are several libraries which can help you (http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ for instance). But the simplest solution could something like this:

```js
// Handle the window scroll event
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // Store the distance scrolled
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop() + 1;

    // Set the scroll speed
    var scrollSpeed = 0.3;
    
    // Update the background position
    $("#add-outer-container").css('background-position', '0' + -(scrolled * scrollSpeed) + 'px');
});
```

```css
body {
    min-height:3000px;
}

#add-outer-container {
    background:url(http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg) no-repeat  fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add-outer-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. That it was what I searching for.

Answer (score 0):

1- from JS remove the line: `$(elem).css('transition', 'all .5s');`
2- in your CSS add to #add-outer-container class:

```
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,0,0.2,1);
```